# Bluetooth network is unavailable error on PowerBook G4

Tags: bluetooth, mac-mini, leopard, powerpc, powerbook

I've got 2 PowerPC Macs, one is a 2005 Mac mini G4, the other is a 2002 PowerBook G4 Titanium. Both have Airport and Bluetooth cards installed and they work fine and both are OS X 10.5.8.

The Mac mini's BT card is built-in Apple and the PB's BT card is 3Com's PCMCIA card and its drivers are http://www.traud.de/bluetooth

Because their Airport cards have limited range as they've got only one antenna, I've tried to connect to Internet over my Android 7 phone's 4.5G and Bluetooth and Bluetooth-Tethering.

On Mac mini G4 I've managed to easily connect to the Internet using Bluetooth Network method but on PowerBook, I get **The Bluetooth network is unavailable** error
[image: Bluetooth Network Error]

On the Console, a new line appears (shortened and simplified)
`[Req OpCode 1104 from: kernel_task (0) ... timeout: 10000] Bluetooth warning: An HCI Req timeout occured.`

When I try to send a file from Powerbook to Android 7 phone, using the send file option at the Bluetooh icon, I can easily send files.

How to do a Bluetooth Network connection over this Android 7 phone?

Comment: You said "both work fine."  How do you know the Bluetooth on the PowerBook is working properly? The 3Com BT driver you linked to appears to be 3rd party - how do you know *that* works?  Can you connect simple BT devices to the PowerBook like a mouse, or a speaker or similar?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The BT on the PowerBook works properly because once it's up and running, I can connect to any BT mouse or keyboard or whatever. On the picture, on the left is a connected BT mouse. And I can send files to Android 7 phone, as I've already stated on the message. So this Bluetooth card should be working fine. I haven't tried it with my BT headphones but I will give it a try soon. Yep the drivers are 3rd party as there were no OS X drivers coming with the card.

Comment: I've just tried connecting my Sony MH100 Bluetooth headphone. The pairing was okey but after the pairing when I selected "use headphone" on the Bluetooth menu, the computer just crashed i.e. I needed to press the power button for seconds to reboot the OS. So the BT drivers may not be perfectly working.

Comment: That's your starting point, then.  You first have to get a stable BT setup on the PowerBook - maybe searching for "better" drivers or maybe a different piece of hardware.

Comment: That's not easy because this BT card was manufactured in February 2002 and the OS X drivers were compiled at around 2005 and haven't got any update since then.